# Is there any way to provide a custom button to approval process accept/reject page

Tags: apex, custom-button, approval-process

I want to understand if there is any way I can put a button which will perform a custom logic in the approval - accept/reject page. i.e. in the following page

[image]

Or I have to create a visual page/ lightning component?

I already looked into the below reference, but there does not seem to be any suitable answer.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009kzbIAA

Comment: Not possible from my understanding. I you want to perform something customizable, for example a button that post a Chatter notification to pending approvers, you need to create a custom VF or Lgtn.Cmp to add this custom buttons and functionalities.